# Concentration inequality on 1-norm of random vector

Tags: random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

I would like to give an upper bound on $\Pr\{||X-\mathsf{E}[X]||_1 > t\}$ where $X$ is a $d$-dimensional random vector with each entry follows i.i.d. binomial $(n,p)$ (so $\mathsf{E}[X]$ is actually a vector with all entry $np$), I found some results about matrix concentration inequalities (such as matrix Berstein) but they are all on 2-norm. Any references about this kind of result on 1-norm?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Actually 1-norm is greater than 2 norm? If we use Cauchy-Schwarz and change it to 2-norm we can get something like $\exp(-2nt^2)$, but we expect the probability to be vanishing with both $n,d$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Sorry I still couldn't understand, maybe it's because of my misleading notations, by $||X||_1$ I mean $\sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|$, so I think we have $||X||_2 \leq ||X||_1 \leq \sqrt{d}||X||_2$ right?